# Most efficient way to cut an output between regex matches?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to parse an

```
lspci -k
```

output by each device. In other words, with this sample output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 5000
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device d000
    Kernel driver in use: i915
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 5000
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 5001
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
```

I want to be able to traverse through each file and associated information individually. My regular expression I'm using to detect the format ??:??.? elsewhere is:

```
grep -E '^[0-9]\w:[0-9]\w\.[0-9]' <<< "$s" | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}'
```

where $s would be how many ever devices on the list in this format. I was using this since I had non PCI devices listed in a different format.

In this case, I was thinking I could get the line number of each match, so pipe the above statement into

```
grep -n
```

then using sed cut from one region to the next, but I feel this wouldn't be an efficient way of going about this. Any suggestions?

Another solution I'm considering is reading in line-by-line and converting the whitespace into some symbol: e.g.

```
tr ' ' '%'
```

and if a line starts with that, it is included. This could get tricky however, because I would need an external variable outside the loop. Of course I could also possibly add a \n after each instance of the regex and then just set the:

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

Given that they are tabbed, a

```
tr $'\t' 'x'
```

works well. However, I feel the most efficient way is still to somehow cut an entire section then grep the information I need, as opposed to going line-by-line with random variables.

Comment: I figured there'd be a simple way to approach this, but not entirely sure what exactly to do with awk. I'd have to set IFS to regex (if possible) or conversely set it to the lack of a \t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code splits each entry from `lspci -k` into sections:

```
$ /sbin/lspci -k | awk -F'\t' 'NF == 1 { ++n; f = 0 } { a[n, ++f] = $NF } 
END { 
    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) { 
        print "section", i; f = 0; while (a[i, ++f]) print a[i, f]; print "" 
    }
}'
```

By setting the input field separator to a tab character, we can identify which lines are the start of a new section by how many fields they have; the start of each section only has 1 field.

The code in the `END` block demonstrates the fact that each field can be reached in the array `a` using the two indices *section number* and *field number*. It just loops through each one but you could customise the logic to print a given field if it matched a pattern, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Are you limited to `lspci -k`? See for example `lspci -mm` and `lspci -vkmm` which are much easier to parse.

I am not sure what your end goal is, but I cooked up an example that you might find interesting. Provided that you're indeed *not* limited to `lspci -k`.

```
#!/bin/sh
for slot in `lspci -mm | cut -d " " -f 1`; do
    driver=`lspci -vkmm -s $slot | grep "^Driver:" | cut -f 2`
    if [ -n "$driver" ]; then
        filename=`/sbin/modinfo --filename $driver 2>/dev/null`
        echo $slot $driver $filename
    fi
done
```